# get previous four weeks

Tags: android, performance, date, datetime

My week start from Friday and end from Thursday, and i get a list of weeks of current month weeks.
In my Code every thing working fine but get current month four weeks but i want previous four weeks not next weeks of current week.

```
 public void getWeeksOfMonth( int year) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    int val = 0;
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentmonth);
    cal.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int ndays = cal.getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(ndays + "<<<ff");
    while (cal.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) != FRIDAY) {
        cal.add(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        ndays--;
    }
    int remainingDays = ndays % 7;
    if (remainingDays == 0)
        ndays += 7;
    else
        ndays = ndays + 7 - remainingDays;

    int inc = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= ndays; i++) {
        String day = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(day + "<<<");
        Log.e("quest", day + "<<<");
        inc++;
        if (val == 0) {
            firstweek = day.substring(0, 6);
            //  weeklist.add(firstweek);
            val = 1;
        }

        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            String s = day.substring(0, 6);

            weeklist.add(firstweek + "   to   " + s);
            val = 0;
            Log.e("weekdayss", "=======week days===========" + weeklist);
            inc = 0;
        }

        if (inc >= 1 && i == ndays) {
            for (int ii = inc; ii <= 6; ii++) {
                String dayi = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                System.out.println(dayi + "<<<");
                Log.e("quest1", dayi + "<<<");
                inc++;
            }
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    if (weeklist.size() == 5) {
        weeklist.remove(4);
    }
    if (weeklist.size() == 6) {
        weeklist.remove(5);
        weeklist.remove(4);
    }

}
```

**Problem**

1. Want to get previous four weeks, not current Month four weeks

**OUTPUT**

```
[
02-Mar   to   08-Mar
09-Mar   to   15-Mar
16-Mar   to   22-Mar
23-Mar   to   29-Mar
]
```

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122813/android-get-previous-week-dates

Comment: No its not my solution

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is to use the [threeten backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) - in Android [here's how to configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Or, if you're using API level >= 26, just use the **java.time** classes.

This API makes things much easier. You can use the `WeekFields` class to define your week (starting on Friday):

```
// week starts on Friday
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 1);
```

The first parameter (`DayOfWeek.FRIDAY`) is the first day of the week, and the second parameter is the number of days in the first week. [Check the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) for more details about how these fields affect the class behaviour.

To get the current date, you can use the `LocalDate` class:

```
// current date
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.now();
```

Then you make a loop that subtracts a certain number of weeks, and use the `WeekFields` to get the first and last day of each week. I also used a `DateTimeFormatter` to print the dates to same format of your output:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
// get previous 4 weeks
for (int i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
    LocalDate pastWeek = dt.minusWeeks(i);
    LocalDate startOfWeek = pastWeek.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1);
    LocalDate endOfWeek = pastWeek.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 7);

    // you can add this String to your weekList
    String week = startOfWeek.format(fmt) + " to " + endOfWeek.format(fmt);
    System.out.println(week);
}
```

Output:

> 23-Feb to 01-Mar
>   02-Mar to 08-Mar
>   09-Mar to 15-Mar
>   16-Mar to 22-Mar

Comment: bp.zone.ZoneRulesException: No time-zone data files registered

exception